# where are the free books the kindle app offers?

Tags: kindle-for-android

According to [its description on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?hl=gb&id=com.amazon.kindle), in the third sentence, it says that the books are free. I installed the *Kindle app* and went to the *Kindle Store* and all the books I looked at so far all have to be purchased.

Where can the free ebooks be downloaded from? Because when I click 'books on device' in the kindle app, it shows none (so I'm guessing I need to download them from somewhere).

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Our site works best with only one question asked per post, so we took the freedom to remove the second one. No need for a separate question for that: Guess the difference between an app and a hardware device should be clear :) Besides, the Kindle tablets are just running Android and the Kindle app, so from that point there's no difference. // As for the free books: Yes, there are some. But the majority is, as you found out, to be paid for.

Comment: @Izzy hm okay, interesting. Right yea I thought if you buy the kindle ebook reader then the books will be for free but guess not. And hm okay thanks.

Comment: No, Amazon usually makes money via content. But see my answer below: I recommend Moon+ (using the Pro myself): supports a load of different formats, and has many nice libraries pre-configured (including my own bookserver :) If that answers your question, please don't forget to click the check-mark next to the answer, to help others see your issue was solved.

Comment: You can try this blog https://kindlebooks.blog/

Answer (score 0):

The majority of books on sites like Amazon, Barnes & Nobles, and the like, are definitly payed for. All of them offer some free books to get you in, but you end up in a "closed ecosystem": you can read them only with their dedicated readers, as they often use their own formats (Amazon) or at least some DRM.

If you want to go for free content, you're much better of chosing an eBook reader app supporting the open ePub format (some exemples include, but are not restricted to: [Moon+ Reader](http://www.appbrain.com/app/moon-reader/com.flyersoft.moonreader), [FBReader](http://www.appbrain.com/app/fbreader/org.geometerplus.zlibrary.ui.android), and [Aldiko](http://www.appbrain.com/app/aldiko-book-reader/com.aldiko.android). At least the first two already ship with a load of free libraries pre-configured, which they can access directly from inside the app.

Comment: This isn't what OP is asking.

Comment: When it comes to DRM-free eBook files, you need to purchase that too. Plus, you can push these DRM-free eBooks to your Kindle cloud.

Comment: Not quite correct, Sachin. There are tons of DRM free eBooks you can simply download. Just not at Amazon. And let's not go hair-splitting: OP obviously wanted to get "free eBooks" in the first place, and Kindle was just the instrument he thought fitting (keyword: X-Y). And no, I won't discuss that here, unless the OP states it himself :)

Answer (score 0):

From Kindle Store, you can only get [popular classics](http://www.amazon.com/s/?node=2245146011) for free. But, Kindle is integrated with many of free eBook providers. For example, on [Open Library](https://openlibrary.org/), you can click `Send to Kindle` link while viewing a free title (Amazon authentication will be required).

See Amazon's [Free eBooks Collection page](http://www.amazon.com/s/?node=2245146011). It gives you all required instructions to get free eBooks from various sites.

---

Also, there's no difference if you read a book with Kindle app on Nexus 7 or [Kindle eBook Reader device](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007HCCNJU).. except Kindle eBook Reader device doesn't have color display & would provide a very-very long battery life.

Comment: There is a difference, if you are prime member, you can only borrow a book on Kindle hardware device. (no option to borron in Android Kindle app)